# Responsive divs within navigation

Tags: header, navigation, responsive

How can I make divs containing images and content in the navigation to shrink together with the browser shrinking. Is there an easy way to achieve it, ideally not using JQuery ?

One of the subjects it Product Cart

```html
<div class="columns cart-container" style="right: 60%; top: 10px; left: 80%; width: 80px;">
<div class="cart">
<div class="show-for-medium-up">
<a class="cart-link" href="/cart">
<div class="recently-added">
</div>
<div class="show-for-small hide-for-ie9-down">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is not correct and not clear. Where are the images supposed to be placed? Please, revise and complete your code so that we can understand wha't are you trying out.
Anyway ...IMHO, even though Jquery is required, if I you want to keep things easy and powerful, I suggest you to use Bootstrap fluid grid system. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: Ups! Previous comment links, my mistake, to old Bootstrap version docs. Correct link to current version is http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid